# Silverlight and WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have WCF querying a table, from that I get one record that I have showing in a datagrid.

How do I set the columns values of that one record to variables and have those variables available to the rest of the silverlight app?

What I am trying to do:
Have WCF query a SQL table
set those results to variables
have a chart react to those variables

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF call should return a type that your current DataGrid is binding too. You can use that same type to pass to your chart. In other words, you don't have to read the values back out of the DataGrid, you already have the values there that your DataGrid is being populated from.

Comment: I need them to be in variables for other things that I am attempting to do based on the variables

Comment: What is the WCF method that you are calling? How do you populate your DataGrid?

Comment: dsc1 context = new dsc1();
LoadOperation<My_View> lo = context.Load(context.GetMy_ViewsQuery("0074"));
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = lo.Entities;

Comment: Ok, fairly cryptic code there, but you have the data you need in lo.Entities, so why not use the same variable to populate your chart etc?

Comment: as stated, the chart is only one thing that I need to populate, I need the values in variables

Comment: That is a variable. If you don't like that variable, then reshape the data how you want it into your own variable, using LINQ for example, or a straightforward foreach loop.

Comment: wait, I missed something from what you just said.  if the table has ID and TechnologyName (and other columns) how do I get the ID and TechnologyName and set them to individual variables. an example if you please

Comment: those will both be properties of an entity in your lo.Entities collection. lo.Entities will be an IEnumerable<something> where something is your entity type that you datagrid is bound to. So you can do foreach(var entity in lo.Entities) { // access entity.ID, entity.TechnologyName here etc }

Comment: OK, I tried the below code and got nothing:  List<getValues> hcpValues = new List<getValues>();
                foreach (var entity in lo.Entities)
                {
//Individual items
                    strGetHCPosition2 = entity.TechnologyName;
                    tbERROR.Text = strGetHCPosition2;
                    MessageBox.Show(strGetHCPosition2);
//build a list
                    hcpValues.Add(new getValues
                    {
                        strGetTechName = entity.TechnologyName
                    });
                }

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. Try var list = lo.Entities.ToList();

Comment: I know I am being a pain here but I am new to Silverlight and C#, can you write out what the entire code should look like, starting from your var list = lo.Entities.ToList(); and on

Comment: I tried this on my own and I get no results: var list = lo.Entities.ToList();                
                foreach (var entity in lo.Entities.ToList())
                {
                    strGetTechName = entity.TechnologyName;
                }
MessageBox.Show("Get TechName: " + strGetTechName);

Comment: playing around with it, I actually got it working, thank you for your efforts and time